# How to concatenate increment operator to PHP

Tags: php

```
  $i = 0;
while ($slider_query->have_posts()) {
              $slider_query->the_post();
              $html ='<div class= "col-lg-3 order-lg-'.$i.' col-md-6 p-0">';
                 $html .= '<div class= "ss-pic">';
                    $html .= '<img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full').'"/>';
                $html .='</div>';
             $html .='</div>';
             $html ='<div class= "col-lg-3 order-lg-"'.++$i.'"col-md-6 p-0">';
                $html .= '<div class= "ss-text">';
                    $html .= '<h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
                    $html .= get_the_content();
                    $html .= '<a href="/gym">Explore</a>';
                
            $html .='</div>';
         $html .='</div>';
```

I want to pre-increment the $i. Can anyone please help me out? I know its a basic, but I have a bit of confusion over the concatenation

Comment: The code in the image you posted differs quite a bit from the code you originally posted.  Can you copy/paste the code from the image as text to the question.

Comment: You mean `++$i` perhaps? Or just write `$i++;` on the first line of the loop. It will increment the value before you concatenate it

Comment: @ADyson ++$i - pre increment

Comment: Yes. It is. You can use that

Comment: @ADyson  Can you please see the code. Actually, I want to increment the first div by 1 and when it comes down to second div then it should be 2 , then again 3 4 etc... like tht

Comment: @NigelRen please help me out . see the code

Comment: So then you just need to increment it before you concatenate it. Still not  really seeing the problem. What exactly happens when you try with ++$i ? In what way was it not what you expect?

Comment: @ADyson YES I want to increment it before concat. What happening is it is directly incrementing to 8

Comment: where are you echoing `$html`? Because you overwrite it each time the `while` loop starts, and again half-way through! So you only ever see the last copy.

Comment: I am echoing it at the bottom outside of the loop

Comment: can you please let me know your email id , so that we can chat there @ADyson

Comment: No need. The solution is trivial - just keep concatenating, rather than overwriting the values before you output them! I added the answer below. (P.S. Don't ask for email IDs on this site, you will never get one. The whole point of the site is to provide public information for future readers, as well as you. If you want a private consultation you'd need to pay, and you can find such people elsewhere online. There is a chat feature here but again it's publicly viewable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So firstly you can pre-increment an integer variable by prepending `++` to it, e.g.

```
++$i
```

. That will work for you, e.g.

```
'<div class= "col-lg-3 order-lg-'.++$i.' col-md-6 p-0">'
```

However, you also have another problem which is preventing you from seeing the results as you are expecting. Every time you write `$html =` - which is twice within your loop, you *overwrite* the contents of `$html`. The previous contents of the variable are destroyed. Therefore, at whatever time you come to echo `$html` to the output, you'll only ever see the last version.

You need to concatenate all the HTML together into a single string without overwriting it.

Put

```
$html = "";
```

just before the loop starts, and then change

```
$html ='<div class= "col-lg-3 order-lg-'.$i.' col-md-6 p-0">';
```

to

```
$html .='<div class= "col-lg-3 order-lg-'.++$i.' col-md-6 p-0">';
```

(note the `.=` there, and also the `++$i` which you forgot)

and lower down, change

```
$html ='<div class= "col-lg-3 order-lg-"'.++$i.'"col-md-6 p-0">';
```

to

```
$html .='<div class= "col-lg-3 order-lg-"'.++$i.'"col-md-6 p-0">';
```

(again just changing the `=` to `.=`.)

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e1ac7b039867eedd22d90dfcdc03e8990419a8f

Answer (score -1):

```
  $i = 0;
while ($slider_query->have_posts()) {
              $slider_query->the_post();
              $html ='<div class= "col-lg-3 order-lg-'.$i+1.' col-md-6 p-0">';
                 $html .= '<div class= "ss-pic">';
                    $html .= '<img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full').'"/>';
                $html .='</div>';
             $html .='</div>';
             $html ='<div class= "col-lg-3 order-lg-"'.$i+2.'"col-md-6 p-0">';
                $html .= '<div class= "ss-text">';
                    $html .= '<h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
                    $html .= get_the_content();
                    $html .= '<a href="/gym">Explore</a>';
                
            $html .='</div>';
         $html .='</div>';
```

I dont think you can increase a value in one loop. you need to add it with numeric value since you want a different value for each `div` in one loop

Comment: it is showing syntax error after+1 and +2

Comment: wrap it in parentheses i.e `($i+1)`